# Is there a way to follow people's activity?

Tags: support, users, recent-activity

Is there a way to follow a particular person (or `List<Person>`) easily? Some people answer the questions in a very educative way, and I don't want to miss them.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know educative was a word.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm

Answer (score 29):

You can subscribe to their activity RSS feed on their user page:

> https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/*{insert-user-id-here}*

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm

Comment: should this work for others SE communities? I'm trying to follow an user in japanese SE

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a particular person in mind?

Check the activity tab of their user page. For example here is yours:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/31699/volkanuzun?tab=activity

Comment: Having to remember each person that you're interested in, pulling up their page, and clicking on their activity feed is hardly "following" them. I'm pretty sure that's not what the question was asking.

Comment: @JavidJamae I have tried to build a more elegant solution for this problem. Check this out http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225503/220601

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm