# User Watch Option

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to follow people’s activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/is-there-a-way-to-follow-peoples-activity)

I see a lot of related questions to watch a question for answers, but is there an option (like in [Jive](http://www.jivesoftware.com/)) where you can watch users for contributions?  There are a lot of users I feel like I could learn a great deal from, and I'd like to be notified when they contribute quality content to a tag of my choice (i.e. email me when user ABC contributes to tag XYZ).

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/stalking-for-fun-and-profit

Comment: Not a dupe and not answered.  I'm not talking about checking RSS feeds and the RSS feed functionality doesn't satisfy what I want.  I want an email, like Jive, when a user I have a 'watch' on posts something in general, or in particular.  I'm not going to check however many RSS feeds for however many users periodically throughout the day.  Following User Activity != User Watch

Answer (score 3):

There is a RSS user feed on every user profile available.

[alt text http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2956/userfeed.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2956/userfeed.png)

Comment: I don't care about RSS feeds.  I want an email, like the question said.

Answer (score 1):

There is the RSS option, of course. Here is [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/97992). It isn't tag-specific, but probably comes close? There is a [tag RSS](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java&sort=newest) too - not sure you can combine them, though.

Comment: You can combine the two when searching, but sadly, no RSS for search results. ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches )

Comment: sounds like a job for greasemonkey.  or maybe yahoo pipes.