# Follow activity of certain users

Tags: feature-request, users, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to follow people's activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/is-there-a-way-to-follow-peoples-activity)
>   [A “friends list” on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice)

Isn't there a simple way to mark certain users as favorites and follow their activity.

Comment: May be just get a user's RSS feed?

Comment: There won't be an "easier" way than the RSS feed, like marking a user as favorite, for the simple reason that it would be like "become a fan of", and other social network things. These sites are ultimately not about people, but about the content.

Comment: Good question. I'm curious to see how SO deals with the social aspect. The content is from people. The fact that people vote for the content links them to the content, it's the soul of Stack Exchange sites. Can users benefit from popular answers as much as they can from the "right" answer? Answer credibility is defined by user reputation, so it might make sense to follow a reputable user to see what other answers he's given (w/o knowing the question beforehand). RSS is too detached. I can envision reputable users sharing reputation to empower other users. -It's people helping people.

Comment: Yes, Omar is articulating what seems to be missing from all the "SO isn't a social network" responses. I would love this feature and have listed possible features and ways to make it not like a social network on this thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice

Comment: I would also be thrilled to see this feature. I would like to see a feed of activity from users I am particularly interested in. Rather than going to each user's page and clicking on a feed, it should be aggregated a "following" page. Like twitter, facebook, etc. Don't know it because it's a "social network thing". It would be useful!

Answer (score 6):

As S.Mark commented, just go to the user profile page and click the [user feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/148244) link at the bottom of that page.

[user feed http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/864/so021.jpg](http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/864/so021.jpg)

Comment: Your image died (but it shouldn't be too hard to replace it).

Answer (score 1):

Hey, a better screenshot! :)

[image]

Comment: This isn't better, where's the freehand circle? ;)

Comment: @ChrisF: cruel.

Comment: Freehand circles on screenshots posted on meta are pretty much mandatory. However, I didn't down-vote - *that* would be cruel.