# Is there a way to follow a user on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, answers

Is there a way to follow the questions and answers posted by a developer on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Since this is a question about SO, it belongs on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is my [SO feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/165297)

Comment: @michael Saw it, don't think it's a duplicate of it, even though the chain leads there

Comment: Nice! Any reason you don't publish it on the chrome store?

Answer (score 62):

I have build [StackEye - A Chrome Extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites) for exactly same purpose.

You can use StackEye

- To follow other users on Stack Overflow
- To watch any question for any new comments and answers on it.

[Install StackEye from Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackeye/pihfndpmcafdecheofkjfkadecoogigm) and go to the profile page of any user and click follow. For example, if you go to [Jon Skeet's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), you get to see this. Just click on Follow button to follow him and get his wisdom :)

[image]

Check out the screenshots available at [Stackapps page](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites). Give it a try if you like it.

Comment: You may wish to post this answer on a more relevant instance of this post

Comment: @Emracool I really appreciate your suggestion but all other questions have been already marked as duplicate of each other. Only this one was left So I posted it here.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the edit and especially for the link (legal). I read all the points and they make a lot of sense. Thanks once again for the useful information :)

Comment: I can't log in to StackApps (not sure why) to leave a comment there... The extension looks great, but has it been tested with a large number of followed users (300+)? Because that's how many I tried to follow and now I'm not sure: either they are all offline, or I exceeded API quota and not getting any information at all.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 Thanks a lot for taking this step towards following a large number of users. However, as per stackexchange API I can only pass 100 ids at a time to get their activity. Anyways, I have already opened an issue https://github.com/blunderboy/stackeye/issues/21
to restrict users to not let them follow more than 25 users. Feel free to make any comment on git or open any issue there.

Comment: Installed it and it is a great extension. Thanks. One question, I followed several users, now the users have activities but sometimes I have to click the extension icon several times then the message window pops up, why?

Comment: @Love When there are too many notifications, it takes a bit of time to read those and show up so if you wait you will see the window in sometime. I'd really suggest to follow only the relevant ones so that you can also read the notifications.

Comment: in 2017, is this still the most up-to-date answer?

Comment: @ZachSmith I don't know any other way to follow a user So probably this hold true till date.

Comment: Any plans to make a Firefox extension?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel StackEye can be easily converted into a firefox extension. This is the first time someone has asked for it. I will add this as a todo item. BTW this is an open source project and I highly appreciate contributions and if anyone is willing to do this, I will be happy to guide him on the steps.

Comment: @sachinjain024 I just saw the Github page. I'll look into it as well!

Comment: I would prefer to have it like that but to express affection, and to have it as a collection of users, whose content is worth to follow and study.

Comment: Nice Idea @FantomX1. Thanks for that. Will prioritize this.

Comment: Thanks, so you understand then that I meant it also as having a publicly available list of most popular users page, so anyone could list them, and pick one from them. That way most popular would not need to be necessarily those with most points.

Answer (score 29):

Every user has an RSS feed. Navigate to the user's page and scroll to the bottom; there'll be a link marked "user feed".

Comment: RSS sounds like a very weird solution to this... I would need an external application or browser plugin which is pointed to the feeds of many users to keep a "friend list", and everyone else to do the same to create a "group".

Comment: This is what I was looking for **mipadi** thanks

Comment: +1 The RSS is useful to know about. As of 2018 there are two tabs on a user page: "Profile" and "Activity". You must click on the Activity tab to find the RSS link at the bottom.

Comment: it is also called User feed, I did a ctrl + f and was searching for RSS and confused as nothing showed up!

Comment: And now it's gone in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

You can see their recent activity on their user page:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/248643?tab=activity#tab-top