# Can I follow some  user?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to follow a user automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41483/is-it-possible-to-follow-a-user-automatically)

As I note that some of users have really very high knowledge here and their answers are always great to read so my question is

I want to **follow** some users on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) so if they post any answer or question so **notification** will appear in my message box. As I can get the notification when [martin-smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) post some answer then I got the message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't get notifications to your inbox, but you can subscribe to an RSS feed of a users activity.

Go to the bottom of the user's profile and click on the "subscribe to users RSS feed" button.

The link has the form:

`http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/[userid]`

Comment: You might find this interesting http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225503/220601