# A follow feed feature?

Tags: feature-request, users, feed, se-quality-project

Recently I got addicted to MathSE and since then coming across rainbow fountains of interesting question and splendid answers

I've discovered many interesting user who contribute a heaven's gold answers to MathSE and the list is expanding fortunately

But the lack of follow feature is bugging me

I searched MetaSE and found similar feature-requests which were turned down under the following pretext:

1. One can use Google Reader as turnaround solution as such
2. SE and it's subsites are QA-sites not social media

But my proposal for feature is different then those:

There should be a follow feature  with a feed stream in different tab than the SE's default one

1. It will enlist "answers" or "questions upvoted" by the user you are following s on the basis of two criteria:

a. Tags: Mathematics(or any other field in general)  is a vast field nobody can have all the  knowledge but there do is some intersection of knowledge/-or interests  say Real Analysis
So your feed will only be populated with those answer/questions of with that tagged/opted  as such

b. Hot Questions/Answers to Hot Questions by that user (say questions above 50 upvotes... the definition hot question for feed stream purposes is for community to decide)

c. Bounty

2. Aim of SE is to be a QA-site rather than social media: so there will not be any such things like Follower or Following count.

Even though it's just mere integer counter in eye programmer but it have drastic psychological and sociological effect as I've observed (e.g. Instagram)

Currently only these points come to my mind any additional suggestion backed by firm foundation  is welcome!

*Here Are some introspecting questions by the esteemed members of this StkEx community:*

---

**Q.1)Why follow a user and not tags?** - [Patrick Hoffmann](https://stackexchange.com/users/970966/patrick-hofman)

We can do open the <user_profile>->[TAGS] and go through the answers posted by them on questions tagged as such but this is not feasible  if the list of awesome contributors lengthens and this is the sole reason for request of feed stream feature
One can't just pay visit to all the esteemed contributors of StkEx,you may even miss out some great answers

Secondly,monotonousness : **The purpose of feed stream is to be randomly curated out of the best content of users you [follow]  that intersect say with yours interest follow Real-analysis, Topology,etc**...

Imagine reading same stuff(I mean belonging to same fields) become boring like having same food palate everyday:the same  mouth-watering food becomes dull

And also reading good stuff related to different fields sparks u one's neuron say maybe you read some answer which has some interesting aspect and then you read another answer.You made a connection whoops: Next thing to upheaval the mankind is on it's way no matter whatever the field :)

Comment: *the user you are following* > typical social media stuff. Why follow a user and not tags?

Comment: Voting is anonymous so I doubt you'll ever be able to follow "questions upvoted by" anyone.

Comment: @PatrickHofman:Please see the edits made regarding your query

Comment: Some older related posts: [Is there a way to follow people's activity?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18978), [Is it possible to follow a user automatically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41483), [A “friends list” on Stack Overflow would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886). (And if you look at posts which are linked there, you will find several other related discussions.)

Comment: @Martin:I already went through all such post before raising my proposal and as such I've addressed those in my post .Kindly,take a relook into the post :)

Comment: BTW if it helps, you might probably find some solutions on StackApps. I quickly found [StackEye - Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on StackExchange sites](http://stackapps.com/q/4454) and [Follow your friends on StackOverflow with FriendOverflow](http://stackapps.com/q/1863), maybe you can find other similar posts there. (And before you write me next comment saying that this is not what you are asking for - in case your feature request is not implemented, it might be useful to know workarounds - some of them are given in these links and in the links from the previous comment.)

Answer (score 5):

SE is not Twitter. If you want to follow a user for his useful contributions in a tag, subscribe to [the RSS feed of the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/1) (change the ID in the URL).

Enabling users to follow another user removes the focus from the content, and brings focus on the content *of a specific user, and that user only*. Why would another (maybe new user) want to contribute if only those who have provided interesting content in the past is shown?

I think it is good to 'follow' activity in a tag you are interested in, maybe only to the posts scoring >= +3, which is already implemented through the questions tab.